# When I use reference.removeValue, the boolean variable always returns true

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

While deleting data from Firebase, I use the remove value function and this function overrides the condition block. My code;

```
boolean deleteDelayControl=true;
if (deleteDelayControl) {
    deleteDelayControl = false;
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("taken_foods").child(food_id);
    reference.removeValue();
}
```

As you can see when I run this code, although I set the boolean variable to false, the control block works every time. What could be the problem?

When I delete this function, the control block works properly: "reference.removeValue();"

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. You initialize `deleteDelayControl` as `true` so the if statement will definitely run. Then you change it to false, but you never use it again, so that doesn't accomplish anything.

Comment: I won't run that block of code again after writing the data there. But even though I did it false, the control state is always working.

Comment: You are creating a new local variable each time this code runs. If you want to remember a value between method calls, you need to store it in a member variable (declared outside the method), not a local variable.

Comment: I have already defined it as a global variable. I wrote that variable there to show you.

Comment: We'll have to see the actual code to be able to tell what's wrong with it.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Q3p5mH6N3M/
You can look my code in this link. 

In fact, the purpose of the code is to provide a 5 second delay after data deletion.  The variable("deleteDelayControl") always returns true, it doesn't work with a delay.